# Aws cli command to get instances that are in public subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Is there a aws cli command to get a list of the instances that are in public subnets?

Comment: If you have the subnet IDs, you can use filter in the list-instances command. However, if you are looking for a command to find public subnets and then list-instances, single command would not be normally possible

Comment: What are the criteria? Just having a public ip? Its not that easy to do for a general use case.

Comment: What are you _actually_ wanting to do with the information? Merely listing instances in public subnets are easy, but it doesn't necessarily mean that they are publicly accessible. This would depend upon the Security Groups associated with the instances and what is actually running on the instances. So, what is the end-goal that you are wanting to achieve once you have this list of instances?

Comment: We are planning to install endpoint protection on all the public facing instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subnet is deemed to be public if the Route Table directs `0.0.0.0/0` traffic to an Internet Gateway.

There is no command that detects "public subnets", so if you wish to automate it, you would need to inspect all Route Tables, look for this configuration, then find all subnets that use that Route Table and then list instances in those subnets.

Instances within those subnets would only be "public" if they have a public IP address and have security group configurations that permit access from the Internet.